# Field filter had an invalid value of...illegal function invocation in one_of(my-subscription); expected at least 2 arguments to one_of but got 1

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have following autoscaler configuration:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: pubsub
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - external:
      metricName: pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.subscription_id: my-subscription-name
      targetAverageValue: "2"
    type: External
```

when I start my aplication I see following log event:

```
unable to get external metric my-namespace/pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{},MatchExpressions:[{resource.labels.subscription_id In [my-subscription]}],}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: googleapi: Error 400: Field filter had an invalid value of "metric.type = "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages" AND resource.labels.subscription_id = one_of("my-subscription")": Illegal function invocation in one_of(my-subscription); expected at least 2 arguments to one_of but got 1, badRequest
```

What could be wrong ? How correct it ?

P.S.
It worked 2 days ago

Comment: What external metrics exporter are you using? Can you provide more information about your environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is became working after I added `resource.type`

```
 metricSelector:
          matchLabels:
            resource.labels.subscription_id: my-subscription-name
            resource.type: pubsub_subscription
```

looks like something was changed on GCP side

Comment: what should be the resource.type for external load balancing